# How to run node webkit app in ubuntu 12.04?(Node js)

Tags: html, node.js, node-webkit

I am new nodewebkit .I have created simple application of hello world.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webkit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello world
    </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
   "window": {
    "title": "Hello world",
    "toolbar": false,
    "position": "center",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 650,
    "min_width": 800,
    "min_height": 650,
    "frame": true,
    "show": false
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

then i have zipped using .nw extension (sample.nw)
after all i have execute by `nodewebkit` command but i getting following error

```
24012:0526/113323:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(162)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/usr/lib/node_modules/nodewebkit/nodewebkit/nw
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/proc/self/exe
[24012:0526/113324:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[24012:0526/113324:ERROR:channel.cc(316)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
```

Can somebody help to run application ? thanks

Comment: Try dropping the folder you have those two files in onto the nw.exe within the nodewebkit folder and see if it opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not installed nodewebkit properly

Please install from https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js latest version as per os and replace nodewebkit tools in where it's installed